# Is bluetooth symmetric?

Tags: bluetooth

Does the bluetooth standard support a client/host relationship between devices, or is the connection symmetric?

The process of initially connecting devices seems to suggest that there is a client/host relationship because one device enters discoverable mode, while the other initiates the connection. However, this doesn't seem ironclad to me, so I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth is indeed a master/slave (client/host) connection. One device is set into discoverable mode while the other initiates the connections. If it is the first connection a pairing sequence is started and the user needs to give a pin code (or with newer device verify the pin code on both devices). All following connection can be made from both devices without being discoverable.

Comment: do the master/slave roles have significance after this first-time connection. This seems borderline out-of-scope for a new question.